# Issue while sending a JSON object with BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: javascript, json, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to send one JSON Object to the HTTP Request body in JMeter using the BeanShell PreProcessor. To model the JSON object I am using java code (with some business logic). Hence I created one BeanShell PreProcessor and wrote the java code as follows,

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    String key="testKey";
    int lastID=5548;
    int totalCount=198;
    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray obj2 = new JSONArray();
    for (int i=1;i<=totalCount;i++)
    {
        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
        item.put("taskId", Integer.toString(lastID+i));
        item.put("taskOrder",1);
        item.put("snapshotTemplateKey",key);
        obj2.put(item);
        obj1.put("changeControlTasks", obj2);
        obj1.put("ccName","Eleven" );
        obj1.put("snapshotTemplateKey",key);
    }
    log.info(obj1);
    vars.putObject("jsonData",obj1);
```

And in the HTTP request body, I am trying to fetch the data as follows,

```
${jsonData}
```

With the above code, It is throwing the below shared error

Request :

```
POST data:
${jsonData}
```

Error in the logs:

```
2017/08/06 07:27:10 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONOb . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method info(  ) not found in class'org.apache.log.Logger'
```

Can any one suggest what is issue with above code and how to resolve the same.

any suggestions or solutions will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj2 hold the data. Use `obj2` instead of `obj1`:

```
 vars.putObject("jsonData",obj2);
```

For log convert toSring

```
 log.info(obj1.toString());
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still facing the same issue

Comment: Add to answer log issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Beanshell won't work as it will fail at this line:

   ```
   log.info(obj1);
   ```

   as you won't be able to print a JSON Object into the log
2. Even if you work it around your HTTP Request sampler won't work for the same reason: you cannot put a JSON Object as a body data as JMeter expects a String there
3. [Beanshell is not the best scripting option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), when you run your test with high number of threads this function will become the bottleneck, you should consider switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and [its performance is much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached. The substitution Groovy code would be something like:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

   def key = 'testKey'
   def lastID = 5548
   def totalCount = 198

   JsonBuilder builder = new JsonBuilder()

   def array = []
   1.upto(totalCount, {
       def taskId = (lastID + "${it}".toInteger())
       array << [getKey: { key }, getTaskId: { taskId }, getTaskOrder: { 1 }]

   })

   builder(
           {
               changeControlTasks array.collect() {
                   [
                           "snapshotTemplateKey": it.getKey(),
                           "taskId"             : it.getTaskId(),
                           "taskOrder"          : it.getTaskOrder()
                   ]
               }
               snapshotTemplateKey "testKey"
               ccName "Eleven"
           }
   )

   vars.put('jsonData', builder.toPrettyString())
   ```